# Get duration of executing script in SQl Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an script to execute and need executing time duration, how can I calculate it?

I think to use this way:

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME
SET @startTime = GETDATE();

--Script


DECLARE @endTime DATETIME
SET @endTime = GETDATE();

PRINT 'Transfer Duration:';
GO
PRINT CONVERT(varchar,@endTime-@startTime,14);
GO
```

But because I use `GO` (and I have to) so there is an error, So what is your suggestion to calculate and print duration of executing script (with `Go`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a table to store the start and the end times, throw in your process ID also. Then use DATEDIFF() to calculate the time elapsed.

```
    CREATE TABLE Profiling(
            spid            smallint        NOT NULL,
            StartTime       DATETIME2       NOT NULL,
            EndTime         DATETIME2
    )

    INSERT INTO Profiling(spid, StartTime)
    SELECT @@SPID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    GO

    -- your queries come here
    -- .....

    UPDATE Profiling
    SET EndTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE spid = @@SPID
    GO

    SELECT DATEDIFF(MS, startTime, EndTime) as MilliSeconds
    FROM Profiling
    WHERE spid = @@SPID
```

Truncate the table from time to time, to avoid collisions of the spid's.

Comment: invalid syntax. Your temp variable dies as soon as you write 'go'

Comment: "Invalid syntax"? on what RDBMS did you got that? It works perfect on SQL Server 2005. "Your temp variable"?? There is not a single (temp) variables used at all in the above code! @@SPID is a build in Tranact-SQL function, not a variable. Please stop trolling.

Comment: I appologize, i tested something similar that failed, your script works fine

Answer (score 4):

Look at [`SET STATISTICS TIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) statement.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the `STATISTIC Time` calculate time for any batch of commands separated by `GO`, and actually with this way my script execution time doubled, and also I need just one Time duration for all of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME
SET @startTime = GETDATE();

-- your sql statement

DECLARE @endTime DATETIME
SET @endTime = GETDATE();

PRINT 'Transfer Duration:';

PRINT cast((@endTime-@startTime) AS TIME);
Go
```

or to be more accurate you can use [SET STATISTICS TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) which Displays the number of milliseconds required to parse, compile, and execute each statement.

Comment: Since `DATETIME` has an accuracy of only 3.33ms, this won't really be very accurate and very useful, I think..... SQL Server 2008 would have `DATETIME2` with an accuracy of 100ns - that *might* be more useful (PS: I didn't downvote - just trying to point out the shortcomings of your recommended solution)

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer Thank you for answer, but in main question I emphasize that I have to use `GO` command,

Comment: @Saeid Go at the end of query check it now I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer  I mean to use `GO` between my script not at the end of it.

Comment: @Saeid you can use Go at the start and end of script check it now I've edited my answer.